# Implementing a C like program in racket using lex/yacc

Tags: parsing, racket, interpreter, yacc, lexer

I was looking at these two resources (https://github.com/racket/parser-tools/blob/master/parser-tools-lib/parser-tools/examples/calc.rkt and https://gist.github.com/gcr/1318240) and although I don't fully understand yet how the main calc function works I wondered if it's possible to extend this to work for a simple c like program just without functions? So it will lex, parse and evaluate ifs, whiles and print statements. So something like `(define-empty-tokens op-tokens ( newline  = OC CC (open-curly/closed-curly for block statements) DEL PRINT WHILE (WHILE exp S) S IF S1 S2 (IF exp S1 S2) OP CP + - * / || %   or && == != >= <= > <  EOF ))`

Here is how I've extended it (the code of the first link) so far to also work with booleans:

So in calcl I added these two lines:

```
[ (:= 2  #\|)   (token-||)]
[(:or "=" "+" "-" "*" "/" "%" "&&"      "==" "!=" ">=" "<=" ">" "<") (string->symbol lexeme)]
```

And then later:

```
(define calcp
  (parser

   (start  start)
   (end newline EOF)
   (tokens value-tokens op-tokens)
   (error (lambda (a b c) (void)))

   (precs (right =)


          (left  ||)
          (left &&)
          (left == !=)
          (left <= >= < >)
          (left - +)
          (left * / %)

         )

   (grammar

    (start [() #f]
           [(error start) $2]
           [(exp) $1])

    (exp [(NUM) $1]
         [(VAR) (hash-ref vars $1 (lambda () 0))]
         [(VAR = exp) (begin (hash-set! vars $1 $3)
                             $3)]
         [(exp || exp) (if  (not(and (equal? $1 0) (equal? $3 0) ))  1 0) ]  
         [(exp && exp) (and $1 $3)]
         [(exp == exp) (equal? $1 $3)]
         [(exp != exp) (not(equal? $1 $3))]
         [(exp < exp) (< $1 $3)]
         [(exp > exp) (> $1 $3)]
         [(exp >= exp) (>= $1 $3)]
         [(exp <= exp) (<= $1 $3)]


         [(exp + exp) (+ $1 $3)]
         [(exp - exp) (- $1 $3)]
         [(exp * exp) (* $1 $3)]
         [(exp / exp) (/ $1 $3)]
         [(exp % exp) (remainder $1 $3)]


         [(OP exp CP) $2]))))
```

But I'm struggling to understand the above code as well as the below. I would lile to change it so that it also to works for ifs and whiles etc. if it's at all possible?

```
(define (calc ip)
   (port-count-lines! ip)
  (letrec ((one-line
        (lambda ()
              (let ((result (calcp (lambda () (calcl ip))  )))
                (when result (printf "~a\n" result)  (one-line))
                )
                 ) ))
    (one-line))
  )
```

Also, this guy seems to be relying on newlines to mark the end of a statement. i.e. you can't have more than 1 statement on one line. I want the program to recognise two statements on one line and evaluate them separately by somehow looking ahead and checking whether there's a new undeclared variable, special keyword or open/closed bracket etc.

Update:

I managed, with the below rules, to build in brag an AST for arith expressions but how do I get rid of all but the important parens so that I can evaluate it?

Eg: with input list: `(list (token 'NUM 17) '+ (token 'NUM 1) '* (token 'NUM 3) '/ 'OP (token 'NUM 6) '- (token 'NUM 5) 'CP)`

I'm getting back:

```
'(exp (((((factor 17)))) + (((((factor 1))) * ((factor 3))) / ((((((factor 6)))) - (((factor 5))))))))
```

Here are my rules:

```
exp : add
/add : add ('+' mul)+  | add ('-'  mul)+ | mul  
/mul : mul ('*' atom)+  | mul ('/'  atom)+ | mul ('%'   atom)+ | atom
/atom :  /OP add /CP | factor
factor :  NUM | ID
```

Comment: UPDATE: Here is what I understand so far: 
1 - one-line is a declared function that when called executes a lambda that:

2 - assigns a value to result, a value which it will receive from calcp.

3 - calcp will have produced this value by executing  a lambda it has received from one-line.
4 - a lambda which when executed calls calcl passing it 'one' value from the lexer.
5 - and so that value will be forwarded to calcp.

Comment: 6 - calcp will be doing its thing and pass back the value which is set to result.
7 - result is then printed 
8 - and one-line is called again recursively
9 - at the end of the function there is a call to one-line to get the thing going right at the start
So at 5) is where I'm confused, how does calcp manage to evaluate an entire expression when it's only received 'one' token from calcl?

Comment: `calcp` is passed a functional which returns a token every time it is called. So `calcp` can use that to acquire as many tokens as it believes necessary.

Comment: So can I not change calcp so that instead of an evaluated results, it returns to me a static expression or a piece of the tree like (assign (id var) (num 5)) which I can then use for a branch in my syntax tree? And so on for all different types of statements? How would I do that?

Comment: Also, where is calcp actually executing this lambda it is receiving?

Comment: you can get `calcp` to do whatever you want by changing the reduction actions in the grammar. Right now, these actions evaluate and return a number. To make an AST, these actions need to build and return an AST node (and if that's what they return, that's what they will recueve in `$1`, ...)

Comment: You'd have to look at the definition of `calcp` to see where it calls its argument, and it may not be easy to see the definition because it is likely that `parser` generates the function. You really should read SICP :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily implement a language with conditionals and looping constructs using an evaluator based on immediate evaluation.

That should be clear at least for loops. If you have something like (using a super-simplified syntax):

```
repeat 3 { i = i + 1 }
```

If you evaluate during the parse, `i = i + 1` will be evaluated exactly once, since the string is parsed exactly once. In order for it to be evaluated several times, the parser needs to convert `i = i + 1` into something that can be evaluated several times when the `repeat` is evaluated.

This something is usually an *Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)*, or possibly a list of *virtual machine* operations. With Scheme, you could also just turn the expression being parsed into a functional.

All of this is totally practical and not even particularly difficult, but you do need to be prepared to do some reading, both about parsing and about generating executables. For the latter, I highly recommend the classic [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* (Abelson & Sussman)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html).

Comment: So yacc cannot do first lexing and then parsing separately? The code above IS using previous evaluated variables for expressions on lines ahead. 

He does that by implementing some kind of memory. I've done an interpreter before in prolog using Backus Naur and building an AST but I didn't find any resources on the net showing how to do this in Racket (which I need to do for an assignment). In Racket, all the inbuilt support I could find for this was yacc so I find it hard to believe that this library used in the above code isn't extendable beyond expression evaluation.

Comment: To implement a loop you're describing, all I'd need to do is some recursion, when I'm at that stage of the parsing, and keep updating that variable whilst checking the while condition until  eg the stored value for that variable doesn't pass the condition, no?

Comment: @nkatz: you could conceivably do that with a top-down parser, but it is not at all easy. However, you have a bottom-up parser, which handles components first, so you don't know that `i = i + 1` is part of a conditional or loop at the moment it is reduced.

Comment: @nkatz: if you know how to build an AST, you can certainly do it in racket. An AST can be as simple as  a Scheme program itself, `(node-type child ...)`. Evaluating an AST is just a top-down tree walk.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. In order to be able to re-evaluate you'd need to keep the expression alive/expanded and the code above immediately evaluates/collapses it?!

Comment: @NKatz: not "the code immediately above". Suppose a loop is nested in a conditional or vice versa? Evaluation is intrinsically top down. Bottom up parsing is bottom up. You glue them together by building an AST bottom up and then evaluating it (or compiling it or whatever) top down.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've seen [here](https://github.com/racket/parser-tools/blob/master/parser-tools-lib/parser-tools/examples/calc.rkt) and [here](https://gist.github.com/gcr/1318240) I managed to implement the lex and parse phase of an interpreter for a simple c-like program. It doesn't have functions in it but it has assignments, variables, conditionals, loops and print statements (As well as arithmetic, it also contains logical expressions.). I'm posting it below, in case others may find it useful (The whole thing including the evaluation phase and samples of input is [here](https://github.com/nkatz01/functional-programming-nkatz01/)):

```
(require parser-tools/yacc //provides you with the lexer, the parser and the lexeme tools eg. string-> symbol, string->number etc - In general, with the ability to map the literals in the input  
         parser-tools/lex
         (prefix-in : parser-tools/lex-sre))

(define-tokens value-tokens (NUM VAR  ))
(define-empty-tokens op-tokens ( newline  = OC CC DEL OP CP + - * / || %   or && == != >= <= > <  EOF PRINT WHILE IF ELSE  ))



(define vars (make-hash)) ;to store the values in the variables 

(define-lex-abbrevs
  (lower-letter (:/ "a" "z"))
  (upper-letter (:/ #\A #\Z))
  (digit (:/ "0" "9")))
 
(define calcl ;lexer is mapping the literals to their tokens or values
  (lexer
   [(eof) 'EOF]
   [(:or #\tab #\space  #\return #\newline  ) (calcl input-port)]
   [ (:= 2  #\|)   (token-||)]
   [(:or "=" "+" "-" "*" "/" "%" "&&"      "==" "!=" ">=" "<=" ">" "<") (string->symbol lexeme)]
   ["(" 'OP]
   [")" 'CP]
   ["{" 'OC]
   ["}" 'CC]
   [ "print" 'PRINT   ]
   [#\,  'DEL  ]
   [ "while" 'WHILE ]
   [ "if" 'IF ]
   [ "else" 'ELSE ] 
   [(:+ (:or lower-letter upper-letter)) (token-VAR (string->symbol lexeme))]
   [(:+ digit) (token-NUM (string->number lexeme))]
   ))


(define calcp ;defines how to parse the program and how the program structure is made up (recursively)
  (parser
   (start   start);refers to the block named 'start' below. Every parser has a start, end, tokens definition, optional error message when needed and operator precedence def.
   (end   EOF)
   (tokens value-tokens op-tokens  )
   (error (λ(ok? name value) (if (boolean? value) (printf "Couldn't parse: ~a\n" name) (printf "Couldn't parse: ~a\n" value)))) 
   (precs   ;sets the precedence of the operators in relation to each other - that is, to which operand they bind stronger
    (left DEL);from lowest to highest
    (right =)             
    (left  ||)
    (left &&)
    (left == !=)
    (left <= >= < >)
    (left - +)
    (left * / %)
    (right OP)
    (left CP)
    (right OC)
    (left CC)
    )
   
   (grammar    ;what is the grammar of my program?
    (start
     [() '()]  ; returns empty list when it matches onto nothing              
     [(statements) `(,$1)]
     [(statements start) `(,$1,$2)] ;we can have more than one statement - one example of the recursiveness 
     )

    (statements /what type of major statements we might have
                
     [(var = exp ) `(assign ,$1 ,$3)]
     [(IF ifState) $2]
     [(WHILE while) $2]
     [(PRINT printVals)  `(print ,$2)]
               
                 
                
              
     )
 
    (ifState ; It's assumed that you cannot have an if inside an if unless it's within curly braces
  
     [(OP exp CP statements) `(if ,$2 ,$4)] /combinations of different major statements
     [(OP exp CP block) `(if ,$2 ,$4)]       
     [(OP exp CP block ELSE statements ) `(if ,$2 ,$4 ,$6)]
     [(OP exp CP statements ELSE block ) `(if ,$2 ,$4 ,$6)]
     [(OP exp CP statements ELSE statements ) `(if ,$2 ,$4 ,$6)]       
     [(OP exp CP block ELSE block ) `(if ,$2 ,$4 ,$6)]
     )
    (while
     [(OP exp CP block) `(while ,$2, $4)]
     )

    (block
     [(OC start CC) $2] ;we can statements or entire program wrapped into curly braces - a block 
     )
   
     
    (var
     [(VAR) $1]
     )
     
    (printVals
          
     [(exp DEL printVals ) `(,$1 ,$3)]
     [(exp) $1]          
         
         
     )
     
        
    (exp [(NUM)  $1] ; smallest (most reducible) chunk in an expression when the chunk is an integer
         [(VAR)  $1] ; smallest (most reducible) chunk in an expression when the chunk is a variable
         [(exp || exp) `((lambda (a b) (or a b))  ,$1 ,$3) ]  
         [(exp && exp) `((lambda (a b) (and a b)) ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp == exp) `(equal? ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp != exp) `(not(equal? ,$1 ,$3))]
         [(exp < exp) `(< ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp > exp) `(> ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp >= exp) `(>= ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp <= exp) `(<= ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp + exp) `(+ ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp - exp) `(- ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp * exp) `(* ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp / exp) `(quotient ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(exp % exp) `(modulo ,$1 ,$3)]
         [(OP exp CP) $2]) ;when the expressions are wrapped parentheses
    )
  
   )
  )
```

Procedure calls the parser passing it a lambda (that calls the lexer providing it with the input) which it will use to get values from the lexer, as many values at a time as it sees fit.
; i.e. according to what the parsing rules above, prescribe

```
(define (calceval ip)
  (calcp (lambda () (calcl ip))))
```

To see the evaluator (unfortunately without much comments yet) see [here](https://github.com/nkatz01/functional-programming-nkatz01)